# 'cannot access a disposed object. Object name 'oracle connection' oracle.DataAccess"

Tags: c#, android, oracle11g, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am making an android application, in that i am using ksoap2 to call a .net c# web service ,
my android app sends a string to web service which extracts user details from oracle database and returns the response concatenated in a string.

i was usually able to retrieve the response correctly. Then suddenly the server has started throwing me the following error  "cannot access a disposed object. Object name 'oracle connection' oracle.DataAccess" , i don't have access to the web service as it is on web server.

I have no clue why this is happening. Some times i suddenly get correct response through same code without any changes.
My Calling method is as bellow

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


public class CallSoap 
{
    public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/"+method_name;

    public  final String OPERATION_NAME = method_name;

    public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "url";

    public CallSoap(){  }

    public String Call(String a)
    {
        SoapObject request = 
            new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

        request.addProperty("data",a);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = 
            new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

        Object response=null;
        try 
        {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            response = envelope.getResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            response=exception.toString();
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

But the same web service runs properly from web browsers application.

I searched every forum possible answer finally ended up here asking this question.
Sorry for not being so clear in description as i am new to all this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem has nothing to do with your Android app. It's purely in the C# web service.

It might be a bug that's only triggered under certain conditions, which do not occur when using the web browser. Nevertheless, the problem is on the server side.

If you built the web service, the start a new question with sufficient information about the service. If not, then you'll need to delegate it to the owner of the web service.

Comment: I felt the same looking forward to get the access to the web service and update my question when i have sufficient information. Still if u can try to gv some idea from .net perspective " Why the connection is getting disposed"

Comment: The problem seems to be inappropriate connection handling (either not correctly disposing of connections or commands or keeping a connection even though it has been disposed / given back to the pool).

Comment: Don't know if i found the solution. But redirecting the web service through another instance of web service that consumes the earlier one solved my problem. I am currently not getting that error.